SQL query - GROUP BY usage
In my table I have three columns: Name, Department and Experience. I want to retrieve the name who got min experience from each department along with department.
I used the below query but it's not working the way I expected
select name, dept, min(exp)
from table
group by dept, name;

Please help.

What's the database?

This can be done by joining a GROUP BY subquery. But there are better ways (somewhat depending on dbms.)

What's the expected result if a department has two persons having the same minimum experience?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to show some extra effort.

consider adding having exp = min(exp) after your group by.

@xQbert, you can't use exp in HAVING without also adding it to the GROUP BY. (Unless as argument to aggregate function.)

Um.. there's a group by in the example... and I said "after the group by"

@shonima did you check the solution that I added below?

You can replace your table name.
SELECT t1.name, t1.dept, t1.exp
FROM table t1
JOIN (
  SELECT dept, MIN(exp) as min_exp
  FROM table
  GROUP BY dept
) t2
ON t1.dept = t2.dept AND t1.exp = t2.min_exp;


Can you also add an explanation?

@jarlh I added a solution above with some explanations.

Assuming your database supports Window functions:

row_number() - creates a rank from 1,2,3 ..n based on the group criteria. In your case, it ranks the experience per department. The order by clause is used to set the order in which rank is created. By default, it is ascending, which means in your case the ranks start with 1,2 based on the lowest experience per department

then we filter out the result by choosing the lowest rank (lowest experience per department) i.e rank = 1


with main as (
  select
    department,
    name,
    experience,
    row_number() over (partition by department order by experience) as rank_
  from table
)
select *
from main
where rank_ = 1

If your Database is Bigquery, Snowflake or Redshift Azure databricks you can use the qualify() function directly to filter the results of a given Window function, no need to create the rank column first and then use it in where clause like I did it in solution 1 above.
select department, name, experience
from table 
qualify row_number() over (partition by department order by experience) = 1

If none of the above are supported try this:

Step 1: Get min experience per department in one CTE.
Step 2: Join the data from the original table to the values stored in the First CTE. Meaning per department match only rows that matches the value of minimum experience.

with min_expereince as (
  select
    department,
    min(experience) as min_exp
  from table
  group by department
)
select 
  department,
  name,
  experience
from table
inner join min_experience 
  on table.department = min_experience.department
  and table.experience = min_experience.min_exp


If you GROUP BY column name instead, of ordinal position your query will be ANSI/ISO SQL compliant, and more portable.

@jarlh replaced group by 1 with group by column name
